# How to hide link button based on a result returned by a class ?

Tags: asp.net, class, detailsview

I am bit new to C# and got a question.

I have a class as below that simply return false ( this is just to test)

```
public class SetAuthority
{
    public SetAuthority()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public static Boolean AuthorizedToAddEdit()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a DetailsView with two link buttons to Edit and add New record. I want to hide the link buttons based on the above class method returning value.

```
<ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" visible='<%# SetAuthority.AuthorizedToAddEdit() %>' 
                            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" visible='<%# SetAuthority.AuthorizedToAddEdit() %>'
                            CommandName="New" Text="New"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Above works file and Edit and New link buttons are hidden when I run the program.

But the question is, I have a separate link button outside of the DetailsView. It is just a link to navigate to another page. I want to hide this in similar way using the same logic. I have the below code in my webform.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" visible='<%# SetAuthority.AuthorizedToAddEdit() %>' 
                            CommandName="OpenAdminPage" Text="Open Admin Page"></asp:LinkButton>
```

But the link button is always visible and seems it is not calling the class and not getting the value back. It appeared to be the class not return any value and can someone help me to identify what is the different between having this and working in DetailsView and not working for a simple link button.

Note: have a workaround where I can call the same method in Page Load event that works fine without any issue. Code is below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean myAllowAdd;
        myAllowAdd = SetAuthority.AuthorizedToAddEdit();

        if (myAllowAdd == false)
        {
            LinkButton1.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that this is for databinding expressions only: `<%#` Since the `DetailsView` is databound it works there.

If you would `DataBind`  the page it worked also for the `LinkButton` outside of the `DetailsView`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

[inline asp.net tags... sorting them all out (<%$, <%=, <%, <%#, etc.)](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)

**Side-note**: be careful with `static` in ASP.NET. The static method does not yet hurt. But if you'd also use static fields you'd enter a minefield since it would be shared across all requests. Your current code-behind "work-around"  is the better approach anyway.